# Disabling or altering system interactions on certain key presses

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, games

So I am running an ubuntu 18.04 server with gnome 3.28 installed. When I play certain games on my system, I have set keybinds such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to perform an action, however; this hotkey is bound to some action that terminates regular programs. While this doesn't happen to the games I play, it means that every time I try to use the keybind, it ignores the first press and I have to press it again in rapid succession for the game to register it. I have tried to rebind the stty keybind as well as establishing a shortcut in Gnome which uses the same hotkey while performing no action. Neither of the options work, to register the hotkey in-game as well as to prevent accidental termination of a process.